Deductive closure of the disjointness axioms
I have an OWL file and, I am interested only in the disjointness axioms in this ontology. I can extract the classes that are disjoint (with RDFLib library). However, I want the closure of the disjoint classes (for example, if class A is disjoint with class B, and class C is a subclass of class B, then class A and C are disjoint). How should I calculate the deductive closure of the disjointness axioms in owl?

isn't that just computing the transitive closure of the subclass hierarchy in a first step, and then simply applying the rule you mentioned?
